# Wordpress Admin Login Redirect Problem

Tags: admin, redirect, login

I have a site that we have developed that we have just moved live.

Another company has the domain name currently so they are redirecting to our IP and DNS.

The website works fine and all forms are working but the admin login form is getting a 'too many redirects' error when trying to load.

We run our development sites from the same server, but on a subdomain and that is working fine.

I've tried removing htaccess and plugins, replacing all the files again, replacing the database and it still doesn't work.  I am at a loss to what the problem could be caused by?

This is a standard WP site, not multi-site, and is running on HTTPS.

Any ideas?

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Try disabling all plugins and testing the WP admin login form. If it works as expected, enable plugins one-by-one to identify which one introduces the redirects. If the issue remains with all plugins disabled, then you'll need to look into your DNS records and virtual host (I assume you're using Apache) entries.

Comment: It could be that the DNS settings haven't fully propagated. I've seen sites partially work but partially not work. Also make sure you've used some sort of database migration plugin so all the serialized URL info in the database has been updated - just editing a couple of wp_options or wp-config isn't usually enough. Finally, perhaps something is going sideways with https - you could try using a force-https type plugin, and always check in an Incognito window whenever you make changes, as your browser caches redirects and you may have fixed it without knowing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved this issue in the end. i removed all the files deleted the cpanel account, and re did everything. This seemed to solve the problem this time!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the database, run the following query:

```
SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name='siteurl' OR option_name='home';
```

*<sup>Replace `wp_` with the prefix that is defined for `$table_prefix` in your `wp_config.php` if it's not the default `wp_`.</sup>*

This is just to ensure that your site is going to the expected location and not still the development one. If it isn't going to the right location, then that would be why your site is going into a redirection loop when you try to log into the admin section.

Change those two keys in the database or alternatively define it in your wp_config.php using:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');
```

Comment: I solved this issue in the end.  i removed all the files deleted the cpanel account, and re did everything.  This seemed to solve the problem this time!